# Sorting dynamic Array of Array of Double in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I create a dynamic matrix in Delphi:

```
AMatrix : Array of Array of Double;
```

and let's suppose that I initialize it this way.

```
SetLength(Amatrix,1000,10);
```

And fill this matrix using some values.  Now, I want to sort the 1000 items on the first dimension on a specific value stored in a specific position on the second dimension (from 0 to 9).

Is there a way to create a TComparer that can be applied directly on the Amatrix without the need to create other data structures (TList or TArray)?

Comment: As far as I know rearranging these kind of arrays requires a lot of memory copying while moving entries from one point in to array to another. If you dont need to soort the actual array, but only need a sorted reference list tothe data in the array I can post a nice example

Comment: Yes, I do know how to create arrays, and I did wrote quicksort, insertion sorts, and all kinds of sorting in the past.  I worked a little bit with TComparer but could not find the way to create a TComparer to sort an dynamic Array of Array

Comment: I can perfectly understand the question and the problem behind it. It should be reopened to allow suitable answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a `TComparer<T>` that can be applied directly on [a variable of type `array of array of Double`] without the need to create other data structures (TList or TArray)?

Let's try it, but we'll use integers for simplicity:

```pascal
program FailedAttempt;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils, Math, Generics.Defaults, Generics.Collections;

var
  A: array of array of Integer;

begin

  A :=
    [
      [5, 2, 1, 3, 6],
      [1, 2, 6, 3, 2],
      [1, 6, 7, 8, 3],
      [5, 7, 4, 2, 1],
      [0, 4, 9, 0, 5],
      [4, 1, 8, 9, 6]
    ];

  TArray.Sort<array of Integer>(A,
    TComparer<array of Integer>.Construct(
      function(const Left, Right: array of Integer): Integer
      begin
        if Left[2] < Right[2] then
          Result := -1
        else if Left[2] > Right[2] then
          Result := +1
        else
          Result := 0;
      end
    )
  );

  for var i := 0 to High(A) do
  begin
    Writeln;
    for var j := 0 to High(A[i]) do
      Write(A[i, j]);
  end;

  Readln;

end.
```

Unfortunately, this won't compile, since `array of Integer` isn't a valid type you can use as `T`. Notice how this is just like how you cannot use `array of Integer` as the return type of a function. And the solution is the same, too: Create a type defined as `array of Integer`.

```pascal
program Solution1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils, Math, Generics.Defaults, Generics.Collections;

type
  TIntArray = array of Integer;

var
  A: array of TIntArray;

begin

  A :=
    [
      [5, 2, 1, 3, 6],
      [1, 2, 6, 3, 2],
      [1, 6, 7, 8, 3],
      [5, 7, 4, 2, 1],
      [0, 4, 9, 0, 5],
      [4, 1, 8, 9, 6]
    ];

  TArray.Sort<TIntArray>(A,
    TComparer<TIntArray>.Construct(
      function(const Left, Right: TIntArray): Integer
      begin
        if Left[2] < Right[2] then
          Result := -1
        else if Left[2] > Right[2] then
          Result := +1
        else
          Result := 0;
      end
    )
  );

  for var i := 0 to High(A) do
  begin
    Writeln;
    for var j := 0 to High(A[i]) do
      Write(A[i, j]);
  end;

  Readln;

end.
```

But in modern versions of Delphi, you don't need to create your own type (and, indeed, that is a bad idea, since different such types are not compatible). Instead, just use `TArray<Integer>` which is indeed defined as `array of Integer` -- this is a dynamic array of integers, just like your `array of Integer`:

```pascal
program Solution2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils, Math, Generics.Defaults, Generics.Collections;

var
  A: array of TArray<Integer>;

begin

  A :=
    [
      [5, 2, 1, 3, 6],
      [1, 2, 6, 3, 2],
      [1, 6, 7, 8, 3],
      [5, 7, 4, 2, 1],
      [0, 4, 9, 0, 5],
      [4, 1, 8, 9, 6]
    ];

  TArray.Sort<TArray<Integer>>(A,
    TComparer<TArray<Integer>>.Construct(
      function(const Left, Right: TArray<Integer>): Integer
      begin
        if Left[2] < Right[2] then
          Result := -1
        else if Left[2] > Right[2] then
          Result := +1
        else
          Result := 0;
      end
    )
  );

  for var i := 0 to High(A) do
  begin
    Writeln;
    for var j := 0 to High(A[i]) do
      Write(A[i, j]);
  end;

  Readln;

end.
```

If you really cannot change the definition of `A`, you can use casting:

```pascal
program Solution3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils, Math, Generics.Defaults, Generics.Collections;

var
  A: array of array of Integer;

begin

  A :=
    [
      [5, 2, 1, 3, 6],
      [1, 2, 6, 3, 2],
      [1, 6, 7, 8, 3],
      [5, 7, 4, 2, 1],
      [0, 4, 9, 0, 5],
      [4, 1, 8, 9, 6]
    ];

  TArray.Sort<TArray<Integer>>(TArray<TArray<Integer>>(A),
    TComparer<TArray<Integer>>.Construct(
      function(const Left, Right: TArray<Integer>): Integer
      begin
        if Left[2] < Right[2] then
          Result := -1
        else if Left[2] > Right[2] then
          Result := +1
        else
          Result := 0;
      end
    )
  );

  for var i := 0 to High(A) do
  begin
    Writeln;
    for var j := 0 to High(A[i]) do
      Write(A[i, j]);
  end;

  Readln;

end.
```

Finally, I should also point out the obvious: it is possible to sort your data without using a `TComparer<T>`. (Indeed, you were forced to do so before generics were introduced in Delphi 2009.)

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I am looking for. Will try to study it a little bit, but it works great.

Comment: What does that CompareValue overload do about the epsilon argument?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: In my example code I use integers, so there is no epsilon argument. If you use floating-point numbers, the default value `Epsilon = 0.0` will be used. This doesn't mean that the actual comparison uses `0.0` as the epsilon; instead, a fairly sensible default value will be used. Specifically, `CompareValue` passes `Epsilon` to `SameValue` which will replace `Epsilon`, if `0.0`, by `Max(Min(Abs(A), Abs(B)) * DoubleResolution, DoubleResolution)` if you use doubles. `DoubleResolution` is defined as `1E-12`.

Comment: Of course one's particular application might require some other epsilon, or some other kind of comparison altogether.

Comment: @Andreas That function is completely inappropriate to use for ordering. It will lead to access violations since the implied equality relation will not be transitive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I agree, but in the integer case it is transitive. (And whether or not lack of transitivity leads to AVs depends on the particular algorithm used.)

Comment: The question is about floating point, and the sort algo that your answer uses requires a transitive relation. So, no, it doesn't depend. The operator you are looking for is classic less than, greater than and equals.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, I automatically transformed the Q from `array of array of Double` to `array of array of Integer` in my head because to me the core issue was about the type system and dynamic arrays, not `Double`s, and I always try to find a problem in its "purest" form. But you are of course right that the original Q was about double and that my original A -- although perfectly correct -- would likely fool readers into doing something wrong. You are right absolutely right about that.

Answer (score 0):

Using @R.Hoeck idea I wrote a simple demo program which create a two dimensions array of double, fill it with random data and sort it using a given column as key.

Sorting is done by creating a list of index/value for the column and then sorting the list.

After sorting, data from unsorted array is copied to another array which will become sorted.

```
unit MatrixDemoMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.Generics.Defaults,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
    TMyRecord = record
        Index : Integer;
        Value : Double;
    end;
    TDynArray2OfDouble = array of array of Double;

    TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        Memo1: TMemo;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    private
        procedure DisplayArray(const Title : String;
                               const Arr   : TDynArray2OfDouble);
    end;

var
    Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    AMatrix      : TDynArray2OfDouble;
    SortedMatrix : TDynArray2OfDouble;
    I, J         : Integer;
    SortCol      : Integer;
    Rec          : TMyRecord;
    List         : TList<TMyRecord>;
begin
    // Give dimension to unsorted array
    SetLength(AMatrix, 10, 3);
    // Give dimension to the sorted array
    SetLength(SortedMatrix, High(AMatrix) + 1, High(AMatrix[0]) + 1);
    // Select column to use as sort key
    SortCol := 2;

    // Fill matrix with random data
    for I := 0 to High(AMatrix) do begin
        for J := 0 to High(AMatrix[0]) do
            AMatrix[I, J] := Random(1000);
    end;
    DisplayArray('Unsorted:', AMatrix);

    // Create a list to sort data
    List := TList<TMyRecord>.Create;
    try
        for I := 0 to High(AMatrix) do begin
            Rec.Index := I;
            Rec.Value := AMatrix[I, SortCol];
            List.Add(Rec);
        end;
        // Sort the list
        List.Sort(TComparer<TMyRecord>.Construct(
                    function(const Left, Right: TMyRecord): Integer
                    begin
                        if Left.Value = Right.Value then
                            Result := 0
                        else if Left.Value > Right.Value then
                            Result := 1
                        else
                            Result := -1;
                    end)
                  );

        // Copy data from unsorted matrix using sorted list
        for I := 0 to High(AMatrix) do
            SortedMatrix[I] := AMatrix[List[I].Index];

        DisplayArray('Sorted on column ' + SortCol.ToString, SortedMatrix);
    finally
        FreeAndNil(List);
    end;
end;

// This procedure will display an array into the memo
procedure TForm1.DisplayArray(
    const Title : String;
    const Arr   : TDynArray2OfDouble);
var
    I, J    : Integer;
    Buf     : String;
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Title);
    for I := 0 to High(Arr) do begin
        Buf := I.ToString + ') ';
        for J := 0 to High(Arr[0]) do
            Buf := Buf + Arr[I, J].ToString + '  ';
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Buf);
    end;
end;

end.
```

Running the demo will display this result in the memo:

```
Unsorted:
0) 293  547  16  
1) 238  503  543  
2) 428  950  663  
3) 150  444  739  
4) 160  388  373  
5) 945  382  417  
6) 863  818  392  
7) 344  131  617  
8) 91  458  330  
9) 370  717  191  
Sorted on column 2
0) 293  547  16  
1) 370  717  191  
2) 91  458  330  
3) 160  388  373  
4) 863  818  392  
5) 945  382  417  
6) 238  503  543  
7) 344  131  617  
8) 428  950  663  
9) 150  444  739
```

Comment: Well, I was looking for a way to sort the matrix directly without the need to use an external index or a second matrix, just like one could do on a simple dynamic array,  In other word, I would like to create a TComparer that would be applied directly on the Array of Array.

Comment: @NormandP. Then it is trivial... and very inefficient as R.Hoeck said because large chunk of data will be moved around as the sort progress. The code will look simpler but performance will drop.

Comment: If needed, I will compare performances on large matrices and may end up with a more trivial solution or go back to my previous implementation (which involves sorting pointers of rows). I cannot duplicate the matrix without the risk of "out of memory" errors.  I often deal with huge matrices.

Comment: "I often deal with huge matrices" Maybe "array of array of double" is not the best data representation if performance matters. Everything depends on what operation you need to do. btw: I duplicated the matrix after sorting to simplify as I understood your problem was sorting not matrix handling. But of course after sorting, the list can be use to swap rows instead of copying it.